# Routing Error in Chapter 7.1.2 of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I've been working through the tutorial for the past few days, and finally hit a snag in chapter 7.

It is in this [step](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code-users_resource) where the line in routes.rb:

```
get "users/new"
```

is replaced with

```
resource :users
```

After I do this, I get a routing error when visiting

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1 - No route matches [GET] "/users/1"
```

instead of the other "Unknown Action" error shown [here.](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#fig-user_show_unknown_action_4)

Per the instructions, my routes.db file looks like this:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :users
  root "static_pages#home"
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

Output from 'rake routes' shows:

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern           Controller#Action
     users POST   /users(.:format)      users#create
 new_users GET    /users/new(.:format)  users#new
edit_users GET    /users/edit(.:format) users#edit
           GET    /users(.:format)      users#show
           PATCH  /users(.:format)      users#update
           PUT    /users(.:format)      users#update
           DELETE /users(.:format)      users#destroy
      root GET    /                     static_pages#home
    signup GET    /signup(.:format)     users#new
      help GET    /help(.:format)       static_pages#help
     about GET    /about(.:format)      static_pages#about
   contact GET    /contact(.:format)    static_pages#contact
```

Does anyone have any insight to get past this? Many thanks.

Comment: Im slightly confused by your question.  You are getting an error when you are expecting a different error, or you don't want an error at all?

Comment: It is my understanding from the tutorial that once "resource: users" is added, I shouldn't get a routing error but instead an Unknown Action error.

Comment: I think you need `resources :users` plural, not `resource :users`.  Your routes should have something more like /users/:id(.:format) in them.

Comment: @mr rogers - thank you!  I was going blind looking at this. That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `resources :users`.

Singular routes are best suited when you have one and only resource to deal with. I.E. `resource :profile` because one user has one profile.

Comment: This was correct - same as mr rogers said above. Thank you both.